# Pintar puntos consultados en una base de datos en un mapa de Mapbox

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox

Buenas chic@s antes que nada gracias de antemano, ahora si al problema tengo un problema al dibujar 
 pintar puntos que consulto en una base de datos.(la consulta esta correcto ya todo esto lo mire)

```
router.get("/map", async (req, res) => {
    const reports = await Report.find({

    });
    res.render("maps/map", {
        reports
    });
});
```

estoy usando hbs para el manejo de html, como pueden ver les envio reports como resultado de la consulta yo he intentado resolverlo de diferentes maneras la mas reciente es esta.
el siguiente codigo es la visata a la cual estoy mandando a renderizar esto cargaria los puntos en un mapa

```
{{#each reports}}

<script> 

    map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [{{longitude}}, {{latitude}}]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "{{state}}",
                "icon": "monument"
            }
        }]
                }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
            "text-field": "{title}",
            "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
            "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
            "text-anchor": "top"
        }
    });

    });
</script>

{{/each}}
```

y esto me pinta el primer pero solo la primera ubicación y me tiran estos errores 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo que yo entiendo es porque al hacer esto en un each se crea varias veces y este es el problema
Alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo.... y disculpen si es estúpida la pregunta para algunos pero para mi no lo es.Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">

<div id='map' style='width: 800px; height: 500px; align-content: center;'></div>


<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY3Jpc2ZvbjYiLCJhIjoiY2swbWlsMjAzMTdvczNjcDdwMjFkcmNqdCJ9.ESku7AdI6kTKFJR33wOf6w';//esta es de flutter
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        hash: true,
        interactive: true,
        minZoom: 0,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11' //'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
    }
    );

</script>

{{!-- {{#each reports}} --}}

<script> 

    map.on('load', function () {
        {{#each reports}}
        console.log({{latitude}})
        {{/each}}

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                {{#each reports}}
                {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [{{longitude}}, {{latitude}}]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "{{state}}",
                "icon": "monument"
            }
        },
        {{/each}}
        ]
    }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
            "text-field": "{title}",
            "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
            "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
            "text-anchor": "top"
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```